# Помогите разобраться с версткой

Tags: css, materialize-css

Использую библиотеку [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/). На главной странице проекта вывожу раскрывающиеся карточки, в три колонки. Есть одна странная особенность - после раскрытия карточки  с деталями отображается только в первой колонке. Во второй и третьей колонке карточка раскрывается, но  с деталями "прячется" за основной  карточки. Причем, если открывать проект на мобильном устройстве, все карточки раскрываются как нужно (опять же, на мобильном они выстроены только в одну колонку). Моих скудных познаний в css недостаточно, чтобы разгадать этот трюк, а когда я вспоминаю, что html каждой карточки выводится циклом, то мой мозг отказывается вообще что-либо понимать - классы и стили у всех карточек одни, да и разметка тоже. Сам html у файла валидный, проверял несколько раз, используя разные инструменты. Код приводит смысла нет, все увидеть воочию прошу по адресу http://qwerq.ru

Comment: К сожалению, многие люди не переходят по незнакомым ссылкам. Если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли - всё-таки придётся выложить код.

Comment: Выкладывать всю библиотеку materializecss?